# Take link in web browser with WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

when I click 1 link in web browser of WP7, the new web has been open. But how can I take link, which I just click, into TextBox to use for other aim? It work nearly FF, when u click any link in 1 any page - this link will be shown on the web address.

thank all for support !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use the `WebBrowser` control `Navigating` or `Navigated` event [(MSDN link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigating%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) and pick up the URL from the event arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.external.notify` within your HTML page in order to notify your Silverlight application. See the following:

http://www.uxmagic.com/blog/post/2011/06/26/Hosting-an-HTML-App-in-Windows-Phone-7-Mango.aspx

Comment: thanks for support but your answer isn't correct in my case :)